# run junit in intellij 12 where each test runs on its own JVM

Tags: junit, intellij-idea

I have a collection of unit tests, using single tones, so each test effects the other (unwanted behavior).
Can I run each test in its own JVM instance (fork=yes) using intellij 12 junit plugin?

Answer (score 3):

I believe what your after is in Run/Debug Configurations.

Run --> Edit Configuration --> Defaults --> JUnit

in the top right of the configuration tab there is Fork Mode

On the defaults this can be changed to `none` or `method`, if you select a particular run configuration you can set to `class` as well

Comment: Wow, it is much slower when you fork -- probably based on per-fork setup time.